# grep bash command into Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh

There is a bash command, I am trying to convert the logic into python. But I don't know what to do, I need some help with that.

bash command is this :

```
ls
ls *
TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
cd xx/xx/autotests/
grep -R "TEST_F(" | sed s/"TEST_F("/"#"/g | cut -f2 -d "#" | while read LINE
```

The logic is inside a directory,  reads the filename one by one, includes all sub-folders,  then lists the file matches.   Any help here will be much appreciated

I tried something like follows, but it is not what I would like to have.  And there are some subfolders inside, which the code is not reading the file inside them

```
import fnmatch
import os
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now()

dir_path = "/xx/xx/autotests"
dirs = os.listdir(dir_path)
TODAY = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

filesOfDirectory = os.listdir(dir_path)
print(filesOfDirectory)
pattern = "TEST_F("
for file in filesOfDirectory:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern):
        print(file)
```

Comment: fnmatch won't work with your pattern, use un*x style patterns. And os.listdir doesn't recurse, by design. You have to use os.walk

Comment: `TEST_F(` isn't a filename pattern, it's the regular expression you're matching inside the files. `grep` syntax is `grep <options> <pattern> <filenames>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.walk()` to scan the directory recursively.

Open each file, loop through the lines of the file looking for lines with `"TEST_F("`. Then extract the part of the line after that (that's what `sed` and `cut` are doing).

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as f:
            for line in f:
                if "TEST_F(" in line:
                    data = line.split("TEST_F(")[1]
                    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar for the insight.  May I ask you one more question if you don't mind?     for example. "cat testcases | grep -v testcase | while read LINE" or "grep -R "@Test" -A 1 | grep void | while read LINE". what will be the best approach to convert bash to python? Thanks a lot

Comment: And also how to add sed and cut into this solution?  grep -R "TEST_F(" | sed s/"TEST_F("/"#"/g | cut -f2 -d "#" | while read LINE    sorry for the dummy question and I am quite new to python

Comment: As I explained, `split()` and `[1]` are doing what `sed` and `cut` do.

Comment: `grep -v testcase` turns into reading the lines of the file, and then doing `if 'testcase' not in line:` in the loop.

Comment: `grep XXX -A 1 | grep void` translates to reading the file line by line. If the line matches XXX, read the next line, then do `if 'void' in nextline:`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar for the further guidance,  May I ask if you can get me an example in code of how to explain this one "grep -R "@Test" -A 1 | grep void | while read LINE".  ?  I am a bit lost for this.

Comment: I am trying to do is the following one: its really difficult for me to convert then into python logic , I am quite new in python.   CLASS=`echo $LINE | cut -f1 -d","`
 TEST_CASE=`echo $LINE | cut -f2 -d"," | cut -f1 -d")" | awk '{ print $1 }'`
 echo "CLASS: $CLASS, TEST_CASE: $TEST_CASE"
 
 FILENAME=`grep -R "class $CLASS" | cut -f1 -d":"`
 AUTHOR=`git log $FILENAME | grep "Author:" | grep -v jenkins | cut -f2 -d"<" | cut -f1 -d"@" | tail -1`
 LAST_UPDATED_BY=`git log $FILENAME | grep "Author:" | grep -v jenkins | cut -f2 -d"<" | cut -f1 -d"@" | head -1`

Comment: Don't try to put code into comments, it's totally unreadable, especially since backticks have special meaning in comment markdown.

Comment: If you have another problem, post a new question. But please don't expect someone to do the python translation for you. You need to try to figure it out yourself first.

Comment: You need to learn the general principles, then it should be straightforward to write the code that does what you want.